# How to solve mismatch vent location for downdraft cooktop?

Tags: exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I am replacing a downdraft cooktop with another. A snag will be matching the new cooktop vent with the existing vent in the wall.  The current vent is on an interior wall and I expect 1-2 inches (or perhaps even more) difference between the center of the vent of the new cooktop and the vent in the wall.
How do I match the two?

The new cooktop will have a deeper well. So the new vent will be 1-2 inches lower and probably off center by 1 inch.

The previous installer is using sheets of steel wool on the outside of vent. Is this ok? Should I use something similar? I guess it is to prevent critters from inside wall or air coming in?

There is a yellow wrapping around the exhaust of fan where it enters the wall vent. I am guessing it is for making a good seal. What is its name? Is that something I buy and add during installation.

[image]

Comment: Pictures of the situation, edited into your question using the Mountain icon tool, will help to get more tuned answers.

Comment: @Triplefault  picture of existing setup added.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. Unfortunately it doesn't reveal the offset that might be required: the setup is all covered so we can't see what's behind the steel wool. (The steel wool might be for critter rejection, and the yellow stuff might be tape or some other seal. Typical duct sealing would be useful when setting up the new vent. But a full opened up picture or three will be needed for better guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of those 4-segment round 90 degree elbows with the slip joints between each segment. When the slip joints are turned, they can straighten the elbow to a straight pipe, or provide for different angles and even offsets of some few inches.

Otherwise, if your situation doesn't allow room for a round segmented elbow, a custom formed sheet metal piece could be used, especially for so few inches' offset.

Comment: The ones I see here https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-26-Gauge-90-Degree-Adjustable-Elbow-26B90E4/100210377#overlay  appear too big. Do they collapse to 1-2 inches?

Comment: You'll have to get one and try to manipulate it. One of the pictures on the HD website shows the segments turned so the pipe is straight. In betweens should be possible too.